# DocuSign E-Signature Api, Docker and Server Proxy

Tags: docker, proxy, docusignapi, e-signature

I am using the e-signature Java SDK for the application that I developed.

The application will run on a docker container and the container on a Linux server.

There is a proxy configured on this server and I have been asked if there is anything that they have to configure regarding DocuSign integration.

[This answer on GitHub](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-java-client/issues/152#issuecomment-653926077) says that SDK would automatically pick up the proxy settings of the system.

What happens on my case. Will it pick the server or the container settings. Should I manually set the proxy settings in code?

Unfortunately I do not have access to the system (or to any similar system) so it is not possible to test the application.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you linked to (https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-java-client/issues/152#issuecomment-653926077) talked about an enhancement request that will enable a specific ApiClient with its own proxy for the Java SDK.
You **do need to updat**e the proxy settings in your code if you know what they are.